# Redirecting locally to a different machine/port depending on the domain name

Tags: apache, redirect, routes, dns, port

I have several web servers (most of them running on Windows) on different machines on my local network.
So far I have configured a domain name to point to my local network's IP, and each server is running on a different port, and I redirect through the router according to the port requested.
What I would like to achieve is to have several domain names pointing to my metwork's IP, and when a user requests a particular domain through port 80, he will be redirected locally to the correct machine on the correct port.

How can I achieve that? Do some routers have this option? Is it possible to centralize all the requests on port 80 to a single machine which will locally redirect?

Thanks a lot!

PS: The web servers I use: Apache2 (x2), JRun, and the embedded servers in XBMC, TightVNC, eMule, and uTorrent.

Comment: a proxy you mean? or you really want to redirect?

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for the slow answer but it took me some time to realize how ignorant I am... I think now a proxy could actually do the job, but I am not sure if it can handle RTMP. I need to run some tests, but do you know a good multi protocols proxy for Windows?

Comment: Well, a proxy is for HTTP traffic, if you need other things than HTTP traffic check for firewall Netwrk Adress Translation functionnalities. I'm a windows noob :-) but if you can get a more detailled version of your question you can maybe try to ask it on Servfault

Comment: Thanks a million! I didn't know that site. I'll update here anyway before posting there. Cheers!